# How do I find multple files with file extension *.nmconnection in Python?

Tags: python

I try to find if there are a single file or files with file extension `*.nmconnection` in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

I try a lots of methods like `os.path.isdir` but I didn't solve it.

My goal is,  if there are files or single file with `*.nmconnection` file extension then I get `True` or If not I will get `False`

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/")
for file in glob.glob("*.nmconnection"):
    print(file)
```

Examples to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Path from pathlib and its glob functionality you could do this:

```
from pathlib import Path

def checkdir(directory, extension='*.nmconnection'):
    try:
        next(Path(directory).glob(extension))
        return True
    except StopIteration:
        return False

checkdir('/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections')
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge To achieve your goal of checking if there are one or more files with the "*.nmconnection" file extension in the specified directory, you can modify your code slightly. Instead of printing the filenames, you can set a flag to True if any such file is found and then break out of the loop

You can use **[pathlib][1]** to do this!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `os.walk()` which returns root directory, directories inside root directories and files inside those directories.

```
import os

os.chdir("/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/")
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk("."):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".nmconnection"):
            print(file)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use the `[pathlib][1]` to solve this -

```
from pathlib import Path

directory = "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/"
suffix = "nmconnection"

def file_exists(directory, suffix):
    p = Path(directory)
    files_generator = p.rglob(f"*.{suffix}")

    try:
        next(files_generator)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: This would also return False if the specified directory didn't exist

Comment: Agree, what is the problem specification? For most of the use case I can think of directory not exists is good enough if ok to return False, otherwise you can catch a more specific exception (i.e. `stopIteration`)

Comment: Whether a file (or files) exists in a directory is a distinct requirement. If the directory doesn't exist then that's a separate issue. Although the language supports *except:* with no further qualification, it is contrary to best practice. In this case *except StopIteration:* should be used because that's what you're trying to determine